# Can i do this to an infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$let , Y=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2...}}}}}$$
$$Then , Y= \sqrt{2Y}$$
$$Y^2 = 2Y$$
$$Y^2 - 2Y = 0$$
$$Y = 0 , Y =2$$
Now y can't be zero so ,
$$Y = 2$$
Is This Correct?

Comment: So far you prove:  If it converges, then it converges to $2$.  The other part is to show it converges.

Comment: You have a sequence here, defined recursively as $y_0 = \sqrt{2}$ and $y_{n+1} = \sqrt{2y_n}$.  Use induction to prove $y_n$ is increasing and bounded -- hence, convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume the number exists and has a value then that is true.

But it could be that the number doesn't exist.

Consider $1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16+..... = M$ then $2M = 2+4 + 8 + 32 + ....$ and $2M + 1 = 1 + 2 + 4+ 8+16 + 32 + .... = M$ so $2M + 1 = M$ and $M = -1$.

That's obviously not true.

ANd this fails because $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^k=\infty$.

However  If $a_0 =\sqrt{2}$ and $a_1= \sqrt {2\sqrt 2}$ and $a_{k+1} =\sqrt {2a_k}$ then *IF* $\{a_n\}$ converges so $Y = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n\ne \infty$, we would be okay.  And we could say $Y=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2...}}}}}$ and $Y= 2$ by your argument.

We can prove $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n\ne \infty$ by noting that $a_0=\sqrt 2 < 2$ and if $a_k <2$ we would have $a_{k+1} =\sqrt {2a_k}< \sqrt {2*2} = 2$. so by induction all $a_n < 2$ so $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n\ne \infty$.

Furthermore $a_{k+1} = \sqrt{2a_k} > \sqrt{a_k*a_k} = a_k$.

So we have $\sqrt{2} =a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < ....... < 2$.  So $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n = Y$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the minus sign. Indeed, the given equation reduces to
\begin{align*}
Y = \sqrt{2Y} \Longleftrightarrow Y^{2} = 2Y\,\,\wedge\,\,Y \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow Y = 0\,\,\vee\,\, Y = 2
\end{align*}

Since $Y > 0$, the sought result is given by $Y = 2$.

Comment: How do you know that $Y>0$?

Comment: You can also think of it as
\begin{align*}
2^{1/2 + 1/4 + \ldots} = 2^{1} = 2
\end{align*}

That is why.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the sequence is convergent and found the limit to be $2$

You need to prove that the sequence is indeed convergent.

The proof is based on the fact that your sequence is increasing and it is bounded above by $M=2$
So go ahead and finish the proof.